# Is it true that Khalid ibn Sa'id ibn al-'As converted to Islam before Abu Bakr?

Tags: sunni

Is it true that Khalid ibn Sa'id ibn al-'As converted to Islam before Abu Bakr, and the first person who, according to Muhammad ibn Abi Bakr - and dozens of scholars and historians to convert to Islam - was Imam Ali (as)? If he confessed this fact in a letter to Mu'awiyah and Umar also converted to Islam before Abu Bakr and Abu Bakr converted to Islam after fifty years. If these things are true, why do we turn the truth upside down so much? And we constantly say that the first man to convert to Islam was Abu Bakr. Do we mean by these forgeries and lies to carve out more virtues for the first caliph, or is it important for us to deny the virtues of Imam Ali (as)?
1- Letter from Abu Bakr's son: ((So he was the first to answer, repent, believed, believed, agreed, and embraced Islam. His brother and cousin Ali, and he is the forerunner of all good, the first people to embrace Islam)).(1)
2- Abu al-Yaqzan says: Khalid bin Saeed bin Al-Aas embraced Islam before Abu Bakr as-Siddiq.(2)
3- Saad and Qas say: Abu Bakr was not the first to become a Muslim, but more than fifty people became Muslims before him.(3)
4- Zohri says: Omar converted to Islam after forty-one men and women.(4)
(1): Explanation of Nahj al-Balagha 3: 188.
(2): Al-Mustadrak Ali Al-Sahiheen 3: 278.
(3): Muhammad bin Saad, I said to my father: Was Abu Bakr the first of you a Muslim? He said: No, and he embraced Islam more than fifty before him... The history of Tabari 1:540.
(4): The History of Islam (The Prophet’s Biography) 180 - Tabaqat Ibn Saad 3: 269 - Sifat al-Safwa 1: 274.

Comment: Again please share the original (Arabic) quotes and if possible links to the sources... And consider editing your post to make it readable. This mess of text is unstructured.

Answer (score -1):

Who were the 'First Muslims'?
Khadija (pbuh) was the first Woman, Zayd (pbuh) was the first free slave, Ali (pbuh) was the first child, and Abu Bakr (pbuh) was the first free man who all became Muslims.

Who was the 'Second Muslims'?
There were different opinions about that. Some scholars believe Muhammad (s)'s closed friend Abu Bakr was the second person, who became a Muslim. Other scholars believe, Abu Bakr was not in town at that time, and that he went to Yemen for his business trip. So in that viewpoint, Ali (pbuh), who was only a 10 year old boy at that time, was the second person who accepted Islam. On the other hand there is another opinion that all these 4 great people accepted Islam on the same day as when Allah (swt) sent the second revelation. But Allah (swt) knows the best. For us, the main point is that they all were the great Muslims who helped Muhammad (s) spread Islam with their life from the very beginning